# python split and remove duplicates

Tags: python, split-function

I have the following output with `print var`:

```
test.qa.home-page.website.com-3412-jan
test.qa.home-page.website.net-5132-mar
test.qa.home-page.website.com-8422-aug
test.qa.home-page.website.net-9111-jan
```

I'm trying to find the correct split function to populate below:

```
test.qa.home-page.website.com
test.qa.home-page.website.net
test.qa.home-page.website.com
test.qa.home-page.website.net
```

...as well as remove duplicates:

```
test.qa.home-page.website.com
test.qa.home-page.website.net
```

The numeric values after "com-" or "net-" are random so I think my struggle is finding out how to `rsplit ("-" + [CHECK_FOR_ANY_NUMBER])[0]` . Any suggestions would be great, thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a regex or use split on the dashes

Answer (score 2):

How about :

```
import re

output = [
"test.qa.home-page.website.com-3412-jan",
"test.qa.home-page.website.net-5132-mar",
"test.qa.home-page.website.com-8422-aug",
"test.qa.home-page.website.net-9111-jan"
]

trimmed = set([re.split("-[0-9]", item)[0] for item in output])
print(trimmed)
# out : {'test.qa.home-page.website.net', 'test.qa.home-page.website.com'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of values, and you want to remove duplicates, you can use `set`.

```py
>>> l = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> set(l)
{1, 2, 3}
```

You can get to a useful array by `str.split('-')[0]`-ing every value.

Comment: @Haveaniceday you're right; I thought it was handled. Proposed an additional step for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to parse the individual lines and a set comprehension to uniqueify:

```
txt='''\
test.qa.home-page.website.com-3412-jan
test.qa.home-page.website.net-5132-mar
test.qa.home-page.website.com-8422-aug
test.qa.home-page.website.net-9111-jan'''

import re 

>>> {re.sub(r'^(.*\.(?:com|net)).*', r'\1', s) for s in txt.split() }
{'test.qa.home-page.website.net', 'test.qa.home-page.website.com'}
```

Or just use the same regex with `set` and `re.findall` with the `re.M` flag:

```
>>> set(re.findall(r'^(.*\.(?:com|net))', txt, flags=re.M))
{'test.qa.home-page.website.net', 'test.qa.home-page.website.com'}
```

If you want to maintain order, use `{}.fromkeys()` (since Python 3.6):

```
>>> list({}.fromkeys(re.findall(r'^(.*\.(?:com|net))', txt, flags=re.M)).keys())
['test.qa.home-page.website.com', 'test.qa.home-page.website.net']
```

Or, if you know your target is always 2 `-` from the end, just use `.rsplit()` with `maxsplit=2`:

```
>>> {s.rsplit('-',maxsplit=2)[0] for s in txt.splitlines()}
{'test.qa.home-page.website.com', 'test.qa.home-page.website.net'}
```